# Is this a digital drawing?

Tags: drawing

Is this a digital drawing? If yes then in which software I can make this?

[image]

Comment: We don't address questions about digital art here.

Comment: Unfortunately since you're asking about a digital tool (the software) and technique, this is not a question that is well-suited to Arts & Crafts. In future, you might want to visit our sister site [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) for asking about details like that.

Comment: @Erica Ok I understood. I was not aware of Graphic design site. Sorry for the question.

Comment: No problem. It's actually almost on topic for us -- if you'd just asked "what method is used for this artwork" we could have let it stand, but the tool recommendation is where we aren't the right site :)

Comment: @Ercia - It may be created digitally, but those programs are made to simulate real world tools, in this case pastels. So the artist may be using a Wacom, but the techniques are the same as if she was using crayon or pastel or colored pencil. It certainly is not Graphic Arts... so where is one to go? (meta, and ok... not exactly the same but pretty close.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it is a digital painting: http://www.cuded.com/2015/08/sweet-digital-art-by-destinyblue/

You can ask the artist which program she uses.

However:

- Photoshop seems to be the preferred program by digital artists (from
  what I've read throughout the internet).
- From the little experience I have in digital art, I think you can
  achieve such effects by any decent drawing app, too (Autodesk
  ScetchBook, Medibang Paint, etc).
- You can also use other non-digital media to achieve such or similar
  effects, such as gouache/tempera, oil paint, (probably) acrylic (I've
  never painted with acrylic, so I can't tell for sure), etc.

Comment: Corel Painter is a good one for simulating real world tools/mediums.

Answer (score 2):

According to her FAQ and [detailed description](http://fav.me/d5x4z8h) of her working method, she does indeed use Photoshop CS6 and "a little" Paint Tool SAI; she uses a Wacom Intuos Pro 5 for digitizing her drawings.

For your information, there are a number of additional widely used software for painting:

- Sketchbook Pro (Win, Mac, industry standard)
- Procreate (iOS great brush dynamics)
- Krita (free, open source, Win, Linux, Mac)
- Blender (paint and sculpt at the same time)

You want to be sure that the software you are using is calibrated to your drawing tablet, and that both tablet and software support things like pressure and tilt.

Personally I use an iPad Pro with Pencil, but you can also use an inexpensive Wacom Bamboo drawing tablet with a computer.